# Form Values are not getting added to the database in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I posted this question earlier but it was then linked to a similar question which don't provide the required solution and was then closed for answering.

So I have created a Flask Application that tracks the movement of products from one location to another while I make movements via the Flask App the form doesn't get validated I tried adding `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}` and `{{ form.csrf_token }}` to the html file that takes input from the user.

If I run this application from the terminal on my command line the form is validated and gets added to the database but if I run the flask app and submit the form in the browser it doesn't.

here is my code for the same

```
class MovementForm(FlaskForm):
    to_location = SelectField('To Location', coerce=int)
    from_location = SelectField('From Location', coerce=int)
    product = SelectField('Product')
    quantity = IntegerField('Quantity')
    add_movement = SubmitField('Add Movement')

@app.route('/movements',methods=["GET","POST"])
def add_movements():
    form = MovementForm()
    form.to_location.choices = [(location.id, location.location_name) for location in Location.query.all()]
    form.from_location.choices = [(location.id, location.location_name) for location in Location.query.all()]
    form.product.choices = [(product.id, product.product_name) for product in Product.query.all()]
    form.from_location.choices.insert(0, (0, 'None'))   
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_movement = Movement(to_location_id=form.to_location.data, from_location_id=form.from_location.data, product_id=form.product.data, quantity=form.quantity.data)
        db.session.add(new_movement)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Product has been moved!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('add_movements'))   
    return render_template('add_movements.html', form=form)
```

Here is my html file

```
 <form action="/movements" method="post">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col">
                {{ form.from_location.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {{ form.from_location(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col">
                {{ form.to_location.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {{ form.to_location(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col">
                {{ form.product.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {{ form.product(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col">
                {{ form.quantity.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {{ form.quantity(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.add_movement(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
        </div>
    </form>
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: I think the issue is that the form return false hence everything after the ` if form.validate_on_submit():` it never runs because return False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove to change in the HTML form the form's action.

```
 <form action="" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            {{ form.from_location.label(class="form-control-label") }}
            {{ form.from_location(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col">
            {{ form.to_location.label(class="form-control-label") }}
            {{ form.to_location(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            {{ form.product.label(class="form-control-label") }}
            {{ form.product(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col">
            {{ form.quantity.label(class="form-control-label") }}
            {{ form.quantity(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.add_movement(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
    </div>
</form>
```

Does this solve the issue?

Also What I suggest you is to add the Flash message into the HTML, because I see that once the Form is submitted it returns back to the 'add_movements' function. Therefore add this:

```
 <div>
     {% for msg in get_flashed_messages%}
         <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
     {% endfor %}
 </div>
 <form action="" method="post">
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
{{ form.csrf_token }}
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col">
        {{ form.from_location.label(class="form-control-label") }}
        {{ form.from_location(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
        {{ form.to_location.label(class="form-control-label") }}
        {{ form.to_location(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col">
        {{ form.product.label(class="form-control-label") }}
        {{ form.product(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
        {{ form.quantity.label(class="form-control-label") }}
        {{ form.quantity(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        {{ form.add_movement(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
</div>
```

> > > > #EDIT

I noticed that something is missing in the product field once coerce in missing:

```
class MovementForm(FlaskForm):
    to_location = SelectField('To Location', coerce=int)
    from_location = SelectField('From Location', coerce=int)
    product = SelectField('Product', coerce=int)
    quantity = IntegerField('Quantity')
    add_movement = SubmitField('Add Movement')
```

---

> > > > EDIT #2

---

In case you run in this kind of issues (which happens all the time) I suggest you to add a print statements and a If/Else clause as well. This will dramatically help you where the issue is ( The issue on your type of problem you posted is that you 'don't see it') and will give you 'eyes.'

For example this is what I would have done:

```
@app.route('/movements',methods=["GET","POST"])
def add_movements():

    form = MovementForm()
    form.to_location.choices = [(location.id, location.location_name) for 
    location in Location.query.all()]
    form.from_location.choices = [(location.id, location.location_name) 
    for location in Location.query.all()]
    form.product.choices = [(product.id, product.product_name) for product 
    in Product.query.all()]
    form.from_location.choices.insert(0, (0, 'None')) 

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print('Form Ok') #if you see the 'Form ok' to see if is validated
        new_movement = Movement(to_location_id=form.to_location.data, 
        from_location_id=form.from_location.data, 
        product_id=form.product.data, quantity=form.quantity.data)
        db.session.add(new_movement)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Product has been moved!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('add_movements'))
     else:
         print('Form Not Ok') #If you see this printed then you see that 
          #is not validated

return render_template('add_movements.html', form=form)
```

Comment: No, it doesn't, still the values aren't reflected in the db

Comment: if you add this flash message, can you see the flash message on the browser?

Comment: The 'coerce' argument in the product field did the job. Thank You!!